# How to import a table from the web in python using html?

Tags: python, html, json, url

I am trying to import the following table in Python:

https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/landry-fields-1.html#players_advanced::none

When I click on 'share and more' and then 'Embed this table', I get the url adress of the html code but I am not sure on how to use this to retrieve the data I am interested in. I am thinking I could use beautiful soup but it would be easier to manage to get the table as csv (or convert from html to csv, which I do not know how to do) and import it directly as a Panda dataframe.

Many thanks!
Tom

Comment: There is nothing I can do with the corresponding html code?

Comment: OK actually I see pandas does support reading HTML: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am misunderstanding you, but that table you linked provides an option to export as a CSV (just below the option to embed as an HTML table). If you are just looking to operate with the data, then that should suffice to import into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./downloaded_data.csv')
```

If you want to load straight from the HTML, however, you can just use pandas's read_html method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/landry-fields-1.html#players_advanced::none')
```

Comment: Thank you dyfontana! Exactly what I was after, I was unaware that Pandas supported html format. And I could not use import as csv because I have around 500 players, so I was looking to automate the process by simply changing the player's name in the url containing the html table (as you did in example 2).